# Groupes des verbes

Tags: grammaire, verbes

Quasiment tous mes livres de grammaire française écrits pour des 
anglophones (e.g., H. Ferrar: A French Reference Grammar ; M.B. Rochester Easy French Step-by-Step ; A. Heminway, French Complete Grammar) disent qu'il y a **trois groupes de verbes réguliers** en français comportant :

1. Ceux du premier groupe (-er ; hormis aller)
2. Ceux du deuxième groupe (-ir ; participe passé en -issant, finissant, agissant, etc.)
3. Ceux du troisième groupe (-re ; tels que vendre, attendre, entendre, rompre, etc.)

et que les autres verbes sont les irréguliers (effectivement **3+1=4 groupes des verbes**).

En revanche, mes livres de grammaire française pour francophones disent qu'il y a **au total trois groupes de verbes**: les deux premiers ci-dessus (réguliers) et le troisième qui comporte les verbes **irréguliers** (c'est-à-dire **sans faisant aucune différence entre les verbes du groupe 3 ci-dessus** et les autres comme atteindre, connaître, etc.)

Je me demande pourquoi cette différence de classification des verbes existe.

Comment: Il y a trois groupes, le deux premiers comme indiqué et le troisième qui contient tous les autre verbes, irréguliers ou non.

Comment: @Toto je pense qu c'est plus pertinent de poster ça en réponse qu'en commentaire ;)

Comment: Merci mais ça ne répond pas à ma question quand même. Pourquoi la différence ? Il s'agit des différentes approaches linguistiques ? Je trouve que c'est une importante différence qui peut faciliter l'appressintage des verbes par les débutants. Ce faisant,  on a trois catégories des verbes réguliers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: Pourquoi les grammaires françaises classent les verbes en trois groupes ?

Parce que c'est la classification officielle qui est enseignée dans toutes les écoles françaises. Elle a été établie par l'arrêté du 25 juillet 1910 qui précise:

> – Les verbes de forme active sont rangés en trois groupes :
> 1º Verbes du type aimer : Présent en e.
> 2º Verbes du type finir : Présent en is ; Participe en -issant
> 3º Tous les autres verbes
> (Arrêté du 25 juillet 1910, in Bulletin de l’enseignement technique, 1898-1920, tome XIII, année 1910, Paris, Librairie Vuibert,
> pages 425-434).

On peut noter que certains grammairiens préconisaient à l'époque une classification en deux groupes seulement suivant les terminaisons du présent de l'indicatif, les verbes en "e, es, e" et les verbes en "s, s, t"

2: Pourquoi les grammaires françaises étrangères classent les verbes en quatre groupes ?

Parce qu'elles ne sont pas tenues de respecter la classification officielle française.

Avant 1910, les verbes étaient aussi classés en quatre groupes en France, suivant la terminaison de l'infinitif: "er, ir, oir et re".

Ni l'une, ni l'autre de ces classifications n'est vraiment satisfaisante en ne rend correctement la complexité de la conjugaison de beaucoup de verbes. En voici [une moderne ici](https://web.archive.org/web/20190104002717/http://www.gabrielwyler.com/page080.html) (Gabriel Wyler - Archive) qui classe les verbes en trois catégories :

> - Verbes majoritaires
>
>   Il y a deux classes de verbes majoritaires : la classe aimer et la classe finir. La classe aimer est divisée en sous-classes correspondant aux radicaux variables (semer, acheter, jeter, employer, etc.).
> - Verbes minoritaires
>
>   Chaque verbe minoritaire se résume ā une spécification canonique commune comprenant quatorze formes simples. Le reste des formes simples sont dérivables des quatorze formes spécifiées. Dans la plupart des cas, un nombre plus modeste de formes canoniques suffirait. Du point de vue de la morphologie computationnelle, c'est une approche simplifiée, modeste.
>
>   Les éléments de la spécification canonique commune :
>
>   - Les 6 personnes du présent de l'indicatif
>   - La première personne du singulier du passé simple
>   - La première personne du singulier du futur
>   - La première personne du singulier du subjonctif présent
>   - La première personne du pluriel du subjonctif présent
>   - La deuxième personne du singulier de l'impératif
>   - La deuxième personne du pluriel de l'impératif
>   - L'infinitif
>   - Participe passé singulier masculin
> - Verbes hyperminoritaires
>
>   Les verbes hyperminoritaires sont des verbes qui débordent le système mis en place pour les verbes minoritaires. Ils ont des formes qui ne peuvent pas être dérivées de la spécification canonique.

Source et lecture recommandée sur ce sujet : [La conjugaison des verbes dans les grammaires du français des XIXe et XXe siècles](https://gerflint.fr/Base/Espagne9/suso.pdf)

Comment: *Parce qu'elles ne sont pas tenues de respecter la classification officielle française.* This shows the fundamental difference between two cultures. In the anglophone world the concept of an "official classification" does not exist. Language is a naturally evolving thing that can be analysed in whatever way makes it easiest to learn. There is certainly a group of verbs (like *attendre* that are sufficiently similar to each other to make them worth learning as a group. But whether you count them a conjugation is arbitrary. No one agrees how many regular conjugations there are in English.

Comment: When I learnt Greek, there were two conjugations: *-mi* and *-o*. But these *-mi* verbs equate to verbs like *sum* in Latin - *suis* in French, *am* in English and are regarded as irregular. The *-o* verbs had some sub-groups (not regarded as separate conjugations) but were split into 4 in Latin, which led to the 2/3 in French. But there was also an *irregular* group (like *volo* which became part of the *-oir* group in French (as *vouloir* is from *volo*). That is a fourth, semi-regular group that I learnt at the school where Harry Ferrar taught, but it was not classed a "proper" conjugation.

Answer (score 2):

À mon avis, c'est parce que ce n'est pas un vrai "groupe". Il suffit de comparer la conjugaison de boire :

> je bois, tu bois, il boit, nous buvons, vous buvez, ils boivent

avec celle de prendre :

> je prends, tu prends, il prend, nous prenons, vous prenez, ils prennent

ou encore apparaître :

> j'apparais, tu apparais, il apparait, nous apparaissons, vous apparaissez, ils apparaissent

ou encore dissoudre (promis, après j'arrête) :

> je dissous, tu dissous, il dissout, nous dissolvons, vous dissolvez, ils dissolvent

Contrairement aux conjugaisons des deux premiers groupes qui sont presque parfaitement régulières, pour les verbes en -re c'est bourré d'exceptions, de radicaux qui changent et qu'on ne peut pas deviner... Et les exceptions concernent tellement de verbes par rapport au nombre total de verbes en -re (il n'y en a pas tant que ça !) que ça ne vaut pas la peine de l'ériger au rang de "groupe". C'est plein de petits "sous-groupes" (les verbes en -oire, les verbes en -oudre...) qui comportent chacun une dizaine de verbes maximum. Autant apprendre par cœur les quelques verbes concernés.

Après, pourquoi on en fait un groupe dans les grammaires pour anglophones : je ne sais pas. C'est sans doute plus simple d'apprendre par cœur les verbes en -re quand on parle français depuis tout petit, et peut-être qu'une règle (même si elle est pleine d'exceptions) peut aider. Mais après pourquoi les verbes en "-oir" ne font pas un groupe, ou les verbes irréguliers en "-ir"... L'inverse est peut-être aussi vrai : c'est peut-être plus simple d'expliquer à un écolier qu'il y a trois groupes, les deux premiers qui sont faciles, et le troisième des verbes compliqués à apprendre plus tard. Alors qu'a priori une grammaire pour anglophones s'adresse à quelqu'un qui parle déjà correctement l'anglais, donc sûrement plus mature...

Comment: Je vous remercie vivement pour cette réponse exhaustive. Veuillez voir et ma réponse qui ne répond pas totalement à ma question mais elle donnent plus de détails sur la façon de présentation des verbes en livres de grammaire française conçues pour des anglophones.

Answer (score 1):

Effectivement, ce livre conçu pour les anglophones est incomplet s'il indique pour le 3è groupe les verbes se finissant en -re uniquement. Il y a aussi les verbe en -oir et en -ir (cf. http://mapage.noos.fr/mp2/verbes_du_3e_groupe.htm).

Comment: Veuillez voir la modification de la question. Évidement les livres pour les anglophones mentionnent les autres verbes (recevoir, mourir, moudre, apercevoir, voir, etc.) et en dédient des chapitres entiers. Peut-être, je n'ai pas été clair. Je m'excuse. (P.S. Je pense c'est une faut de frappe mais si+il=>s'il).

Comment: Euh oui, effectivement "s'il". :P Sinon, le troisième groupe est bien celui des verbes irréguliers, tous ceux qui ne rentrent pas dans les deux premiers groupes, en fait (cf. [https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frlesgroupes.php](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frlesgroupes.php)).

Answer (score 1):

Pour résumer :

- Le premier groupe contient les verbes en *-er* sauf *aller*.
- le deuxième les verbes en *-ir* dont le participe présent se termine en *-issant* (finir, vieillir)
- le troisième groupe **tous** les autres verbes, qu'ils soient en *-er* (uniquement aller), en *-ir* avec un participe présent qui ne se termine pas en *-issant* (par exemple dormir) ainsi que les autres terminaisons (pouvoir, prendre). Ces verbes peuvent être réguliers ou irréguliers.

Il n'y a pas d'autre groupe de verbes.

Comment: C'est comme ça que c'est expliqué dans les grammaires pour francophones et à l'école française, mais apparemment pas dans les grammaires pour anglophones. OP se demande pourquoi.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Oui, mais en tant que Français, je ne peux pas expliquer cette différence, étant donné qu'elle n'existe pas.

Comment: Donc tu postes une réponse pour dire "je ne sais pas" ? C'est (apparemment) un fait que les grammaires pour anglophones ont un groupe supplémentaire. OP sait déjà que dans les grammaires françaises il n'y a que trois groupes. Ta réponse n'apporte aucune information à part un bizarre accès de chauvinisme.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: ce n'est pas ce que je dis dans ma réponse, je donne le contenu de chacun des groupes de verbes tel qu'ils sont.

Comment: OP est déjà au courant, relis la question...

Answer (score 1):

Je poste un complément qui ne répond pas à ma question (pourquoi cette différence) mais qui montre quand même comment les grammaires du français pour des anglophones traitent les verbes **réguliers** en -RE (*pas tous ceux en -re !*) et comment elles diffèrent de celles destinées aux francophones et de celles conçues pour le FLE (Français Langue Étrangère).

Source : https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/regular-re-verbs/

et M. Offord: A Student Grammar of French, Cambridge University Press.

> Ce groupe comporte tous les verbes en **-andre, -endre, -ondre,
> -ordre, -endre** (**hormis prendre et sa famille**).
>
> Il comporte aussi les verbes en **-ompre** qui sont conjugués de la même façon hormis la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du singulier du présent de
> l'indicatif où un -t est rajouté à la racine (stem) du verbe.